# Windows vs Linux for Android-NDK App builds

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to develop an App that makes use of some heavy C++ code.

From what I have understood, I have two choices.
Build the library outside Android Studio and then import it, or put the C++ source code directly in Android Studio to let it build.

If I choose to build the library **O**utside Android Studio, I can use (**OW**): **W**indows or (**OL**): **L**inux.

At the same time, I know I can run **A**ndroid Studio on either (**AW**): **W**indows or (**AL**): **L**inux.

My question is, can there be any performance difference in the App product running on the phone, depending on a specific approach I would follow (**OW+AW**/**OW+AL**/**OL+AW**/**OL+AL**/**AW**/**AL**)?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate a C++ library into your Android application, from the performance point of view there's absolutely no difference. The difference in all those your mentioned options is the build process of your C++ library (the files with .so extension, i.e. shared library) which will be later integrated into your final .apk executable file. The Android NDK is doing everything at one place, but aside from performance, you should also consider other factors like development and testing capabilities, based on your project and your (and your peers') active skills. Speaking of the performance, it mostly depends on the number of calls between Java and C++ parts - the less data goes back and forth the better for the performance.